# How to "git add" specified type of files?

Tags: git

Usually we add new files like below:

```
git add .
```

That will add all files. But I'd like to add only the specified type of files, e.g. *.c, *.cpp, *.h...
So I will do it like this:

```
git add "*.c"
git add "*.h"
git add "*.cpp"
```

But this seems not convenient, do you have better solution?

Comment: maybe a combination of ".gitignore" and the normal "git add ." ? Do you want to always ignore the other files?

Comment: Yes. Some file types are not known to me, but I am sure they are not source codes. I know .gitignore(I need to list all the ignored types, not easy for me), but is there .gitaccept(you know what I mean)?

Comment: In [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14451324/237105) there's a direct way to achieve `.gitaccept` behaviour.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65919461/1896134

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.gitignore:

```
*
!*/
!*.c
!*.h
!*.cpp
```

This will work with subdirectories as well.

Comment: This tells git not to ignore subdirectories. If you don't need files in subdirectories, omit this line.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could make an alias

```sh
git config alias.accept "!find|egrep '\.(c|h|cpp)$'|xargs git add"
```

then run like this

```
git accept
```

[`ref`](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/06/helpful-command-aliases)

Comment: Since globbing will be done by `bash`, it will not go into subdirectories. At least `git add **/*{c,h,cpp}`

Comment: Other people working on the project will be puzzled seeing many untracked and unignored files.

Comment: Updated version (1) will add every single file in matching directories (eg named `a.h`)

Comment: (2) will walk into `.git` directory which is quite huge sometimes

Comment: (3) `find` can do filtering itself presumably more efficiently than `egrep` in pipe

Comment: (4) wont work for files with linebreaks in names (use `-x0` in `xargs` when the project is not yours)

Comment: `--global` applies to **all** repositories, *including* uncreated repositories - if you're `ignoring` a large set of files, doing this on a per-project basis is probably safer.