# Is there a way to just commit one file type extension from a folder?

Tags: git, version-control, commit, file-extension

I have a folder with a lot of stuff and I would like just to commit ".c" extension files. Is there a command to do this or do I need to add each file name manually?

Comment: easy enough `git add *.c && git commit -m 'My commit'`

Comment: If you _never_ want to commit files of a particular extension, use [gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: uhhh, seems good - I was trying `git add .c`, let me check here to see if it works haha

Comment: Yeah, I've read about "git inore" but it's too much powerful for this little job - thanks for the typ anyway; @self Works like a charm dude, thank you! add as an answer thus I can accept =D

Comment: Actually, `git add *.c` doesn't even involve `git` in the file selection process: `*.c` is interpreted by the bash, so you can list your .c files with `echo *.c`... It's called globbing, and it really pays off to know how it works.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to add all files with a specific file extension, all you have to do is specify it at the time you go to stage the files using a wildcard.

`git add \*.c`

Here `.c` can be any extension you want.

Comment: This did not work for me. I was trying to add xml files in different paths in my project. git add *.xml did not work, git add \*.xml worked for me.

Comment: My answer states that you must change the `.c` part to any file extension and it will work. Please think of `.c` as a placeholder value.

Comment: Yes, I changed the .c to .xml in my case. I guess the comment above might have been misleading, `git add \*.xml` worked for me not `git add *.xml` as in Sergey's answer

Comment: Same here, `git add *.c` does not work, yet `git add \*.c` does. Maybe this answer needs an update.

Comment: Update: with the backslash issue, you need to check your current directory. I always find it easiest to work from the largest directory, then commands such as `git add *.c` - or whatever your extension is - will work.

Comment: Something like `git add '*.c'` ended working for me.

Answer (score 70):

For me, just  `git add *.c` didn't work. I encountered fatal error like this:

```
git add *.php
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
wp-config.php
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

So, in this variant git tried to add ignored files.

But such variant:

```
git add \*.php
```

worked flawlessly.
By the way, you can do git diff the same way:

```
git diff -- \*.php
```

Comment: this makes sense if bash globbing or git is globbing. Cool. Thank you

Comment: Escaping the `*` with a `\ ` did the trick on zsh shell (OS X). Just doing `add *.extension` works fine on bash shell.

Comment: `git add *.js` (e.g.) works for me - only if the file with the extension that you are looking at is in the same directory! `git add \*.js` adds `.js` files in all subdirectories, you're correct. So without the backslash, the glob is expanded by bash or zsh or whatever, and only matches in the current directory, but with the backslash, the glob is dealt with by git and works in subfolders.

Answer (score 20):

@Ryan's answer will work if you only care about files directly in the folder, but dont care about adding files of the given extension from subfolders.

If you want to add all files of the same extension in the base folder and all subfolders recursively you can use:

```
git add [path]/\*.java
```

to add `*.java` files from subdirectories, or

```
git add ./\*.java
```

for the current directory.

(From [`git add` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_examples))

Answer (score 10):

Duplicating the other answers with a tiny twist: to include files in the current folder and subfolders via a mask e.g. `*.xml` you could use:

```bash
git add ':/*.xml'
```

> NOTE: Using single quotes will prevent the shell (sh, bash, zsh, etc) from expanding the `*` character and will pass the parameter to git as-is so that git handles the glob expansion and not your shell. 
> *Without* the quotes `git add *.xml` will get expanded, and the actual arguments passed to git will be a list of matching files generated by
> your shell, e.g. `git add 1.xml 2.xml 3.xml...`

Comment: Indeed, just `git add :/*.pdf` produced and error "no matches found: :/*.pdf"... and then I saw your answer!

Comment: This works for `git diff -w ':/*.md'` as well!  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Using a simple `*` wildcard works fine, if *you in the same directory* as the files you want to add:

```
git add *.c
```

If you are in a different subdirectory of your repository, then you could use a pathspec with a magic signature, as [described in the git glossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec), to add *all files* with `.c` extension *in any directory in your working tree*:

```
git add :/*.c
```

Any git pathspec starting with `:` has special meaning. In the short form, the leading colon `:` is followed by zero or more "magic signature" letters. The magic signature `/` makes the pattern match from the root of the working tree, even when you are running the command from inside a subdirectory.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mac which comes with zsh, you need to use quotes.

```
git add *.rb
zsh: no matches found: *.rb
```

Using quotes should work:

```
git add '*.rb'
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me. You need to add `\` before the wildcard like below.

```
git add \*.c
git add \*.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the git ignore file rules [gitignore_pattern_format](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format), seems git add act as the same way. Recursive subdirs by leading `**`, and `*.c` match c type files, that is:

```bash
git add **/*.c
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I commit all specific files without doing add like this:

```
git commit -m "My commit message" -- "*.myFileExtention"
```

Example - Commit all kotlin files:

```
git commit -m "My commit message" -- "*.kt"
```

For you, it will be:

```
git commit -m "My commit message" -- "*.c"
```

Answer (score 0):

In powershell visual code I simply did:

```
git add *.scss
```

all this type off files were added.